# Get trace call list of PHP eval or override it manually

Tags: php, eval, exploit

I am investigating a still undiscovered zero day exploit in Revive Adserver. An attack happen on one location and the attacker was able to invoke an `eval` which was already in the development and production version of Revive Adserver code base.

I have investigated the `access_logs` and they indicate the user was doing a POST attack on delivery script `fc.php` but the payload of POST still remains unclear.

The code base of Revive Adserver is very mixed, old and weird at times. There are lots of points where an `eval` is called in the code, and one might find something like:

```
$values = eval(substr(file_get_contents(self::$file), 6));
```

Which is actually a Smarty template thing, but it looks really scary.

As mentioned, lots and lots of `eval` appearances are throughout the code and it would take a whole lot time to go through each one at this time.

Is there a possibility to override `eval` function in PHP to display some trace information, i.e. from which file it was called, on which line did it occur?

If not, is it possible to do this by modifying PHP's C/C++ source code and recompiling it altogether?

Or is there a PHP extension or some tool which can trace all `eval` callbacks throughout a script?

And if there's no such thing, it would be great if someone would develop it since it would speed up investigating malicious code containing `eval`'s.

Comment: You can turn off `eval` by putting it in the  `disable_functions` - that will issue a function not found error, so then you can use a custom error handler  `set_error_handler` where you can do `debug_print_backtrace` or simply throw an exception.

Comment: I know that, but that is not my business. I need to find at which point the script is exploited.

Comment: What about renaming the Smarty `eval` to something else, add logging there, and then do a find and replace on every `eval` in the code? This would also patch up the bug as you wouldn't have any actual PHP `eval` instances... assuming you aren't actually using it for something non-Smarty.

Comment: Looking into this further, there isn't a Smarty `eval` per se, but creating your own function (say, `smartyEval` or whatever) as a wrapper, and finding and replacing all instances of `eval` would still work I believe. You'd still have your security bug in this case, however (as initially you'd just pass whatever `smartyEval` receives to `eval`) but you could toss in whatever logging you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a possibility to override eval function in PHP to display some trace information, i.e. from which file it was called, on which line did it occur?

Sort of.

You can add `eval` to `disable_functions` in `php.ini`.  Then when you call `eval` you'll get the fatal error `function eval not found` or such.

Then with a custom error handler.

```
   set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
       if(false !== strpos($errstr,'eval')){
           throw new Exception();
       }else{
           return false; //see below
       }
       //debug_print_backtrace() - I prefer exceptions as they are easier to work with, but you can use this arcane thing too.
   });
```

Or something like that (untested).

Unfortunately you cannot redefine `eval` as your own function. Eval is not really a function, its a language construct like `isset`, `empty`, `include` etc... For example `function_exists('empty')` is always false.  Some are just more "function" like then others.

In any case you'll probably have to disable `eval`, I cant really think of a way around that.

***Tip***

Don't forget you can do this:

```
  try{
       throw new \Exception;
  }catch(\Exception $e){
      echo $e->getTraceAsString();
  }
```

Which both suppresses the exception (so execution continues), and gives you a nice stacktrace.

***Tip***

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE

So given the above, you can/should return false for all other errors.  Then PHP will report them.  I am not sure it really matters much in this case, as this isn't really meant to be in production code, but I felt it worth mentioning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First example with error handler should do the work. Checking whether functions: `echo, isset, empty, eval` (which are not functions, but language constructs), will always return `false`, but you certainly cannot re-define them in any way.

Comment: `But I am not sure if eval is a "real" function.` - I was afraid of that.  I avoid eval like the plague.  We're forced to have it disabled on our server., compliance stuff. So I never use it.

Comment: @omerowitz - I updated the answer so as to avoid confusion.